# Entity framework core database first, crear las clases de modelo de tablas en especifico

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Estoy creando las clases de modelo por medio de **Entity Framework DataBase First** con el siguiente comando en la consola:

> Scaffold-DbContext 'Server=DESKTOP-IODH4BJ\OPUSDB;Database=EJEMPLO
>   OPUS;Trusted_Connection=True' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
>   -OutputDir Models

Con este comando me crea todas las tablas de las base de datos y yo solamente quiero unas tablas en especifico.

Me podrías ayudar con el comando correcto para crear los **Modelos** de clases de tablas **en especifico**.

También para preguntarles lo siguiente.
¿Se pueden crear los modelo de clases de las vistas creadas en sqlserver con este comando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para crear solo los Modelos de determinadas Tablas de la base de datos, debes indicarlo mediante la opción **-Tables**:

> **-Tables** Tabla1, Tabla2, Tabla3, ...

---

Si quieres consultar el resto de opciones del comando **`Scaffold-DbContext`**, te aconsejo leas este artículo [Entity Framework Core Database First en aplicaciones .NET MVC](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2018/6/6/entity-framework-core-database-first-en-aplicaciones-net-mvc)

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios Rafael, soy nuevo aquí  y no conozco muy bien, pasare al articulo recomendado.